# How to generate date series with corresponding varchar column

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to generate date series with text column?

Say I need 'varchar 1', 'varchar 2', 'varchar 3' with generated dates like this:

| varchars | date |
| --- | --- |
| varchar 1 | 2020-02-01 |
| varchar 2 | 2020-02-01 |
| varchar 3 | 2020-02-01 |
| varchar 1 | 2020-02-02 |
| varchar 2 | 2020-02-02 |
| varchar 3 | 2020-02-02 |
| varchar 1 | 2020-02-03 |
| varchar 2 | 2020-02-03 |
| varchar 3 | 2020-02-03 |

How can I achieve this? What would be the right sql? I have managed to generate_series with dates, but have no clue how to do it with corresponding varchar column.

Thanks beforehands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=100796cbc3fc6f2a963cb8115b809954)

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` on the `generate_series()` function for that

```
SELECT
    varchars,
    my_date
FROM (
    VALUES ('varchar 1'), ('varchar 2'), ('varchar 3')
) as t(varchars)
CROSS JOIN generate_series(
    my_start_date, my_end_date, interval '1 day'
) as my_date
```

Comment: Buy I do not have "mytable" from which to take varchars. I need to generate from blank, something like: select "v1","v2","v3", generate_series

Comment: Did you have a look at the linked fiddle? ;) There I demonstrated how you can achieve this. However, adjusted the answer

Comment: That's brilliant man! Thank you very much! :)